# How to group svg elements

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I am displaying bar chart. Each bar is combination of a rect and a circle element.
Now, I want to group each rect, circle into a group element **like this.**

```
<g class="bar_group">
  <rect class="bar" ..></rect>
  <circle class="rounded_edge" ..></circle>
 </g>
<g class="bar_group">
  <rect class="bar" ..></rect>
  <circle class="rounded_edge" ..></circle>
 </g>
```

**How to group them like above ie one group for a rect and circle pair only?**
right now it is coming as all rects and circles in one group only. ie a group under which all rects and circles.

```js
var data = [
        {
          type: "s1",
          value: 4,
        },
        {
          type: "s2",
          value: 2,
        },
        {
          type: "s3",
          value: 5,
        },
      ];
      var margin = { top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 0, left: 30 };
      var width = 300;
      var height = 220;
      var innerHeight = height - margin.top - 10;
      var barWidth = 20;
      var barMidpoint = barWidth / 2;

      var svg = d3
        .select("svg")
        .attr("class", "d3svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

      var svgG = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate( -6, 0)");
      // X AXIS CODE
      var xScale = d3.scaleBand().range([margin.left, width]).padding(0.4);

      xScale.domain(
        data.map(function (d) {
          return d.type;
        })
      );
      var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
      // call x axis
      svgG
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(20,${innerHeight})`)
        .call(xAxis);

      // Y AXIS CODE
      var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([innerHeight, margin.top]);
      yScale.domain([
        0,
        d3.max(data, function (d) {
          return d.value;
        }),
      ]);

      var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickFormat(function (d) {
        return d;
      });

      svgG
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "y-axis")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left + 25},0)`)
        .call(yAxis);

      // DISPLAY BARS
      svgG
        .selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
          return xScale(d.type) + 28;
        })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
          return yScale(d.value);
        })
        .attr("width", barWidth)
        .attr("height", function (d) {
          return innerHeight - yScale(d.value);
        });
      svgG
        .selectAll(".circle")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("cx", function (d) {
          return xScale(d.type) + barMidpoint + 28;
        })
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
          return yScale(d.value);
        })
        .attr("r", barMidpoint);
```

```css
 .bar {
        fill: steelblue;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="500"></svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sought Solution**

You currently do two enter cycles, one for the `rect`s and one for the `circle`s. For each you append to a common parent (`svgG`).

Instead, in order to achieve your goal, "to group each rect, circle into a group element", we can do one enter cycle for a parent `g`:

```
  // Create groups:
  var groups = svgG
    .selectAll(".group")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "group")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
      // will ease placement of circles/rects:
      return "translate("+(xScale(d.type) + 28)+","+ yScale(d.value) +")";
    })

  // append child elements, one of each per parent g:
  groups.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", barMidpoint)
    .attr("r", barMidpoint);

  groups.append("rect")
    .attr("width", barWidth)
    .attr("height", function (d) {
      return innerHeight - yScale(d.value);
    });
```

We have one `g` per item in the data array. Also, the datum of the parent is carried forward to the children, so you can still use `function(d)` when setting properties.

We also simplify the styling of the data and the positioning by applying style and positional properties to the `g`.

```js
var data = [
        {
          type: "s1",
          value: 4,
        },
        {
          type: "s2",
          value: 2,
        },
        {
          type: "s3",
          value: 5,
        },
      ];
      var margin = { top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 0, left: 30 };
      var width = 300;
      var height = 220;
      var innerHeight = height - margin.top - 10;
      var barWidth = 20;
      var barMidpoint = barWidth / 2;

      var svg = d3
        .select("svg")
        .attr("class", "d3svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

      var svgG = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate( -6, 0)");
      // X AXIS CODE
      var xScale = d3.scaleBand().range([margin.left, width]).padding(0.4);

      xScale.domain(
        data.map(function (d) {
          return d.type;
        })
      );
      var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
      // call x axis
      svgG
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(20,${innerHeight})`)
        .call(xAxis);

      // Y AXIS CODE
      var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([innerHeight, margin.top]);
      yScale.domain([
        0,
        d3.max(data, function (d) {
          return d.value;
        }),
      ]);

      var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickFormat(function (d) {
        return d;
      });

      svgG
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "y-axis")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left + 25},0)`)
        .call(yAxis);

       // Create groups:
      var groups = svgG
        .selectAll(".group")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "group")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
          // will ease placement of circles/rects:
          return "translate("+(xScale(d.type) + 28)+","+ yScale(d.value) +")";
        })

      groups.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", barMidpoint)
        .attr("r", barMidpoint);

      groups.append("rect")
        .attr("width", barWidth)
        .attr("height", function (d) {
          return innerHeight - yScale(d.value);
        });
```

```css
.group {
        fill: steelblue;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="500"></svg>
```

**Better Solution**

The better solution is to use one path to draw your rounded shape, such as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52372808/7106086). We build a path generator to draw the shape, and then use that to create the path:

```
 svgG.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
        pathGeneratorFunction(params);
   });
```

This way we avoid having two shapes to worry about when we are only representing one data point.

If we wanted to be fancier, we could design a function to simply take the datum of the point and return a path string with the following pattern:

```
   .attr("d", generator);
```

But, I'm just demonstrating the simpler version here:

```js
var data = [
        {
          type: "s1",
          value: 4,
        },
        {
          type: "s2",
          value: 2,
        },
        {
          type: "s3",
          value: 5,
        },
      ];
      var margin = { top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 0, left: 30 };
      var width = 300;
      var height = 220;
      var innerHeight = height - margin.top - 10;
      var barWidth = 20;
      var barMidpoint = barWidth / 2;

      var svg = d3
        .select("svg")
        .attr("class", "d3svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

      var svgG = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate( -6, 0)");
      // X AXIS CODE
      var xScale = d3.scaleBand().range([margin.left, width]).padding(0.4);

      xScale.domain(
        data.map(function (d) {
          return d.type;
        })
      );
      var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
      // call x axis
      svgG
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(20,${innerHeight})`)
        .call(xAxis);

      // Y AXIS CODE
      var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([innerHeight, margin.top]);
      yScale.domain([
        0,
        d3.max(data, function (d) {
          return d.value;
        }),
      ]);

      var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickFormat(function (d) {
        return d;
      });

      svgG
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "y-axis")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left + 25},0)`)
        .call(yAxis);

      // DISPLAY BARS
      svgG
        .selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
           return bar(xScale(d.type) + 28,                 
                      innerHeight,
                      barWidth,
                      yScale(d.value),
                      barWidth/2,
                      1)
         })
  
  
function bar(x,y,w,h,r,f) {
    // Flag for sweep:
    if(f == undefined) f = 1;
    // x coordinates of top of arcs
    var x0 = x+r;
    var x1 = x+w-r;
    // y coordinates of bottom of arcs
    var y0 = y-h+r;

    // assemble path:
    var parts = [
      "M",x,y,               // step 1
      "L",x,y0,              // step 2
      "A",r,r,0,0,f,x0,y-h,  // step 3
      "L",x1,y-h,            // step 4
      "A",r,r,0,0,f,x+w,y0,  // step 5
      "L",x+w,y,             // step 6
      "Z"                    // step 7
     ];
    return parts.join(" ");
}
```

```css
.bar {
        fill: steelblue;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="500"></svg>
```